# Could not cast value of type UINavigationController not navigating in the Main Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift5, uistoryboardsegue, xcode12.5

I know there are lots of similar posts but none answered my situation. All of the posts I’ve seen only deal with the Main storyboard. I’m navigating to a different storyboard called Date_Popup which has a VC embedded in a NC. The thing is that this code works on iPhone so I know the segue.identifier, Storyboard ID and the VC ID are correct. Also, I’m using this same code in 7 of my older apps and it works fine there. I’m frustrated that it works there and not in this new app. I’m not sure if this is an Xcode problem or what. I left the commented out code so readers know I’ve tried it both ways. If I comment out the line that throws the error the code execute but then the preferredContentSize doesn't get set.
Thanks for any help.

This is where I get the error.

```
popupVC = segue.destination as! Date_Popover_VC
```

Her's my code.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        if segue.identifier == K.Segue.to_Date_Popover
        {
            var popupVC = UIStoryboard(name: K.StoryboardID.date_Popup_SB, bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: K.StoryboardID.date_Popover_VC) as! Date_Popover_VC
            let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: popupVC)
            
            // let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: K.StoryboardID.date_Popup_SB, bundle: nil)
            // var popupVC: Date_Popover_VC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: K.StoryboardID.date_Popover_VC) as! Date_Popover_VC
            // let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: popupVC)
            
            let deviceName = UIDevice().type
            let deviceString: String = ("\(deviceName)")
            
            if deviceString.contains(K.theDevice.iPad)
            {
                popupVC = segue.destination as! Date_Popover_VC
                
                if ModelData.isInline()
                {
                    popupVC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 320, height: 300)

                } else {

                    popupVC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 350, height: 410)
                }

                navigationController.isNavigationBarHidden = true
                
            } else if deviceString.contains(K.theDevice.iPhone) {
                
                present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                navigationController.isNavigationBarHidden = false
            }
            
            popupVC.theDate = dateFld_Outlet.text!
            popupVC.dateDelegate = self
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is really nothing useful to be said. The error is self-explanatory. If `popupVC = segue.destination as! Date_Popover_VC` crashes, that is because the destination of this segue is _not_ a Date_Popover_VC. As the error message says, it is a UINavigationController instead. You are the only who can see your storyboard and your segue, so fixing that is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out where I want wrong. On the main storyboard where the storyboard reference to the date popover is linked to the segue. The storyboard needs to be the name of the storyboard and the Referenced ID needs to be the name of the VC on that storyboard. The storyboard is chosen from a drop-down menu. The Referenced ID needs to be entered. It actually has nothing to do with a UINavigationController so the error verbiage is a bit misleading.

[image: The Main Storyboard]

[image: Storyboard Reference]